# Tem como gerar um .WAR no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, engenharia-de-software, apk, android-eclipse

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que preciso ser gerada em APK e .WAR; Gostaria de saber se há uma maneira de fazer isso no Android Studio , ou terei de desenvolver duas aplicação em ambientes diferentes, ou se existe uma outra IDE que faz isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aconselho voce usar o IntellIJ IDEA [(Download)](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=mac) ao invés do Android Studio, no IDEA voce teria melhor acesso a ferramentas para tal, alem de poder fazer o mesmo que o android studio e ter mais compatibilidade com o netbeans e o eclipse.

[EDIT]
Aqui: [Arquivos formato .war](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(formato_de_arquivo)), a wiki para arquivos ".war" se voce não tiver conhecimento do assunto